# Data Driven testing in Postman Tool

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, api-testing, web-service, data-driven

Can anyone please let me know how the data-driven testing is done using the Postman?

I read some post in the online, it seems to be by using collection we need to run the collections at the time we can able to upload the CSV file and JSON for Data driver.

When I tried to upload the CSV the iteration count is not showing automatically

Can anyone show some simple example to perform this task? It will be helpful for automation testing for web services

Answer (score 5):

### Update

I have tested with a simple CSV file and it indeed alters the iteration count automatically. So my suggestions for you are:

- update Postman to latest version if not yet done so
- **double-check your CSV**, is the data in a correct format? I think this is a probable cause. Can you share it?

### Original answer

In Postman, go to the menu `Collection` and select `Runner`.

There you'll see the following screen where you can both select a data file and the iteration count.

[image: Postman Collection runner]

Comment: Thanks for your information. Here my problem is after uploading the SCV file the iteration count is not showing automatically. I saw in one of the videos it is updating automatically based on the input in the file. And one clarification is whether I need to pass the parameter as empty or with data in the body. Because the input data is coming from CSV

Comment: @Anand updated my answer

Comment: @Anand let us know how it works out, and if my answer helped, don't forget to accept it please :)

Comment: @ FDM - Really thanks for your answer, now the iteration is working fine for me. I have one more clarification. My inputs are from the CSV file so I need to pass the request parameters without values in the body correct   Attached below screenshot for your reference

Comment: Screenshot  1. https://www.screencast.com/t/WWkDk1ubjw5 https://www.screencast.com/t/P2S4zFjq7fYA   - Please let me whether am doing anything wrong here

Comment: @Anand please accept this answer ans post a new question for your other issue. Otherwise things will get confusing. Thanks.