# How do I verify a value from a CSV file using Postman test

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, postman

I'm using Postman to push data from a CSV in my Google cloud bucket to an app. I need to write a test to verify that one of the values in the CSV is all in uppercase.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data Driven testing in Postman Tool](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/31161/data-driven-testing-in-postman-tool)

Comment: What is your goal? Are you going to verify your test data with postman? What should be the test case step by step?

Comment: Could you add details like how are you pushing the csv from google cloud to app , i have added answer for a local csv

Comment: please add comments to reopen the question if you are looking for data driven approach

Answer (score 1):

you cannot read files from local system in postman other than for iteration or sending it as request.

The two options you have is :

1. **Copy paste all the csv content and paste it in an environment variable , then:**

In your pre-requiste or test script:

```
console.log(pm.environment.get("data"))
const parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync')

//Environmental variable where we copy-pasted the csv content
const input =pm.environment.get("data");

const records = parse(input, {

 columns: true,

 skip_empty_lines: true

})


console.log(records)
```

2. **Pass environment variable through command line using powershell :**

   ```
    $a= Get-Content -raw .\1.csv

    newman run .\test.postman_collection.json -e .\test.postman_environment.json -k -r "cli,htmlextra" --env-var data=$a
   ```

Now use the same above pre-requisite script.

Answer (score 0):

The variable [pm.request.body](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#pmrequest) contains all info about your request body.

On the [Pre-Request Scripts tab](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/pre-request-scripts/) you can set up checks as you do on the *Tests* tab:

```
pm.test("All data is uppercase", function () {
    // You can use pm.expect() pm.request.body to validate things about your request body.
});
```